# Problems writing to 2-Dimensional arrays, Embedded C

Tags: c, embedded

I am having trouble understanding what is going on with my code, mainly regarding 2D arrays. I am trying to use a function in my communication file to decode a command string from a terminal. I want it to break the string down and output the answers by updating the global buffers. I am having trouble writing to these arrays and I do not understand why. In the code below I just assigned a value to the USART1_Command char array where in the actual program it comes from a terminal.

Main and declarations:

```
//Global declarations//
#define USART1_BUFFER_SIZE (100)
#define MAX_COMMAND_INT_VALUES (50)
#define MAX_COMMAND_STR_VALUES (50)
#define MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH (50)
char USART1_Buffer[USART1_BUFFER_SIZE];
uint16_t USART1_Write_Index = 0;
char USART1_Command[MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH] = {0x00};
uint16_t USART1_Command_Int_Values[MAX_COMMAND_INT_VALUES] = {0x00};
char **USART1_Command_Str_Values;

void main(void){
  USART1_Command_Str_Values = (char **)calloc(MAX_COMMAND_STR_VALUES, sizeof(char *));
  uint16_t i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < MAX_COMMAND_INT_VALUES; i++){
    USART1_Command_Str_Values[i] = (char *)calloc(MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH, sizeof(char));
  }

  strcpy(USART1_Command, "TESTCOMMAND,45,36,21-TEST1-TEST2");
  USART1_Command_Decode(USART1_Command, USART1_Command_Int_Values, USART1_Command_Str_Values, MAX_COMMAND_INT_VALUES, MAX_COMMAND_STR_VALUES, MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH);

  while(1){

  }
}
```

and the function:

```
void USART1_Command_Decode(char *command, uint16_t *int_values_buffer, char **str_values_buffer, uint16_t int_values_buffer_size, uint16_t str_values_buffer_size, uint16_t str_values_size){
  uint16_t i = 0;
  uint16_t j = 0;
  uint16_t length = strlen(command);
  
  int16_t Int_Values_Index = -1;
  bool Int_Value_Flag = false;

  char **Int_Values;
  Int_Values = (char**)calloc(int_values_buffer_size, sizeof(char*));
  for(i = 0; i < int_values_buffer_size; i++){
    Int_Values[i] = (char*)calloc(str_values_size, sizeof(char));
  }

  const uint16_t Max_Str_Values = 50;
  int16_t Str_Values_Index = -1;
  bool Str_Value_Flag = false;
  
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++){

     switch(command[i]){

        case ',': //Signifies integer value//
            if(Int_Values_Index < int_values_buffer_size){
                Int_Values_Index++;
                Int_Value_Flag = true;
                Str_Value_Flag = false;
                j = 0;
            }
            command[i] = 0x00;
            break;

        case '-': //Signifies string value//
            if(Str_Values_Index < str_values_buffer_size){
                Str_Values_Index++;
                Str_Value_Flag = true;
                Int_Value_Flag = false;
                j = 0;
            }
            command[i] = 0x00;
            break;

        default:
            if(Int_Value_Flag){
                Int_Values[Int_Values_Index][j] = command[i];
                command[i] = 0x00;
                j++;
            }
            if(Str_Value_Flag){
                str_values_buffer[Str_Values_Index][j] = command[i];
                command[i] = 0x00;
                j++;
            }
            break;
     }
  }

  //Convert integer strings to integers//
  for(i = 1; i <= Int_Values_Index; i++){
      int_values_buffer[i] = atoi(Int_Values[i]);
  }


  for(i = 0; i < int_values_buffer_size; i++){
    free(Int_Values[i]);
  }

  free(Int_Values);
}
```

Comment: What kind of trouble are you experiencing?

Comment: if it is a micro controller code forget about the malloc, calloc and this kind of dynamic allocation

Comment: The device is an STM32L432KC programmed through ST-Link using CrossStudio 4.7. The problem that I am having is that the 2D dynamic arrays in the function are not taking the values. The values are present in the USART1_Command array but the 2D arrays after the assignments are still zero. I want all the integer values to be separated and placed in USART1_Command_Int_Values, the char[] values after the '-' symbol should go into the USART1_Command_Str_Values, and everything before the first ',' should stay in USART1_Command

Comment: Note: There are no  2D arrays here.  With `Int_Values[Int_Values_Index][j]`, `Int_Values[Int_Values_Index]` is a pointer.

Comment: @progroober As I wrote forget about malloc and calloc. They have no use in the uC development. Usually heap is set to about 512 bytes and it is getting fragmented literally instantly. programming uCs you need to ferget a big part of the C functions you use when programming big computers

Comment: @P__J__ when I take out the calloc() it worked, for the `USART1_Command_Int_Values` but I still cannot get it to write to the `USART1_Command_Str_Values`

Comment: you have a debugger. Step through your code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are correct, I apologize, this is a char pointer to pointers. I get the terminology mixed up because I forget that arrays technically do not exist in C.

Comment: Ok I have stepped through this several times, is this the correct way to pass the global pointer `char USART1_Command_Str_Values[MAX_COMMAND_STR_VALUES][MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH]` to the function with argument type `char **str_values_buffer` using `USART1_Command_Str_Values` in the function call?

Comment: C does have arrays, yet `Int_Values` is best describe as a [pointer to pointer to char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+**Int_Values).  IAC, `atoi(Int_Values[i])` is suspicious as It appears as `Int_Values[i]` appears to lack null character termination.

Comment: @P__J__ is correct, you shouldn't be using dynamic memory allocation in microcontrollers, and the main reason isn't even heap fragmentation or leaks, but that it [simply doesn't make any sense](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/171581/6102), because it is not a PC.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, the way that I was able to make it work was as follows:

Declaration of Global variables:

```
#define MAX_COMMAND_INT_VALUES (50)
#define MAX_COMMAND_STR_VALUES (50)
#define MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH (50)
char USART1_Command[MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH] = {0x00};
uint16_t USART1_Command_Int_Values[MAX_COMMAND_INT_VALUES] = {0x00};
char USART1_Command_Str_Values[MAX_COMMAND_STR_VALUES][MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH];
```

Function:

```
void USART1_Command_Decode(char *command, uint16_t *int_values_buffer, uint16_t int_values_buffer_size, uint16_t str_values_buffer_size, uint16_t str_values_size, char str_values_buffer[str_values_buffer_size][str_values_size]){
  uint16_t i = 0;
  uint16_t j = 0;
  uint16_t length = strlen(command);
  
  int16_t Int_Values_Index = -1;
  bool Int_Value_Flag = false;

  char Int_Values[int_values_buffer_size][str_values_size];
  
  for(i = 0; i < int_values_buffer_size; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < str_values_size; j++){
      Int_Values[i][j] = 0x00;
    }
  }

  int16_t Str_Values_Index = -1;
  bool Str_Value_Flag = false;
  
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++){

     switch(command[i]){

        case ',': //Signifies integer value//
            if(Int_Values_Index < int_values_buffer_size){
                Int_Values_Index++;
                Int_Value_Flag = true;
                Str_Value_Flag = false;
                j = 0;
            }
            command[i] = 0x00;
            break;

        case '-': //Signifies string value//
            if(Str_Values_Index < str_values_buffer_size){
                Str_Values_Index++;
                Str_Value_Flag = true;
                Int_Value_Flag = false;
                j = 0;
            }
            command[i] = 0x00;
            break;

        default:
            if(Int_Value_Flag){
                Int_Values[Int_Values_Index][j] = command[i];
                command[i] = 0x00;
                j++;
            }
            if(Str_Value_Flag){
                str_values_buffer[Str_Values_Index][j] = command[i];
                command[i] = 0x00;
                j++;
            }
            break;
     }
  }

  //Convert integer strings to integers//
  for(i = 0; i <= Int_Values_Index; i++){
      int_values_buffer[i] = atoi(Int_Values[i]);
  }

}
```

Function Call:

```
USART1_Command_Decode(USART1_Command, USART1_Command_Int_Values, MAX_COMMAND_INT_VALUES, MAX_COMMAND_STR_VALUES, MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH, USART1_Command_Str_Values);
```

Thank you @P__J__ for the help!

EDIT:
I found the main problem with my original code, I was having problems with stack overflow because I was misunderstanding the allocation for stack and heap in Cross Studio. I had 256bytes of stack when I thought that I had more like 20KB. I allocated 16KB to stack and 8KB to heap, all the problems with `malloc()` and `calloc()` have disappeared along with the array writing issues. I apologize to everyone for the unnecessary question.

Comment: Instead of `for (i = 0; i < int_values_buffer_size; i++) { for (j = 0; j < str_values_size; j++) {      Int_Values[i][j] = 0x00;  }  }`, could simplify with `memset(Int_Values, 0, sizeof Int_Values);`

Comment: You really don't want to allocate 50x50 bytes on the stack, trust me. Move that array to static storage. Also, clearing that whole chunk each time the function is called is a massive time bottleneck, just keep track of the size used instead.

Comment: Lots of other problems here too. Once you get it all working, I'd recommend posting the full, working code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Lundin I would be happy to do that, and I appreciate this feedback because I am relatively green to C programming and I have about the same experience with embedded C. I am trying to write a generic file that I can use for commands through a serial terminal on any project, right now I am using it to control some WS2811 and WS2812B led light strands. This is all hobby stuff too so there would be no problems with intellectual rights or anything like that